# utf-8 encoding error in seq2seq model

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, keras

Hi I'm working on `Language translation` using `Keras`. I have a text file with `English text` and a file with `Hindi text`.

I'm facing `"UnicodeDecodeError:"`. And I believe maybe its because it is unable to convert non-unicode to unicode.

Please let me know how to go about it. The github link is below

https://github.com/shashankg7/Seq2Seq/tree/master/seq2seq

Code Snippet:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import codecs
import pdb
import numpy as np
#from utils import preprocess_text, text2seq_generator


def preprocess_text(file_path_src, file_path_tar, max_feats):
    f_src = open(file_path_src)
    f_tar = open(file_path_tar)
    vocab = defaultdict(int)
    freq_src = defaultdict(int)
    freq_tar = defaultdict(int)
    sents_src = [line.rstrip() for line in f_src.readlines()]
    sents_tar = [line.rstrip() for line in f_tar.readlines()]


def preprocess(self):
    # Preprocessing source and target text sequence files
    self.vocab_src, self.vocab_tar, self.sents_src, self.sents_tar = 
    preprocess_text(self.path_src, self.path_tar, self.max_feat)


 if __name__ == "__main__":
      pre = preprocess('C:\\Users\\anagha\\Desktop\\Language-Translation\\Seq2Seq-master\\Seq2Seq-master\\seq2seq\\training.hi-en.hi', 'C:\\Users\\anagha\\Desktop\\Language-Translation\\Seq2Seq-master\\Seq2Seq-master\\seq2seq\\training.hi-en.en', 5500, 15)
     pre.preprocess()
     for e in range(1):
         print("epoch no %d"%e)
     for X,Y in pre.gen_batch():
         print(X)
```

Error :

```
  Using TensorFlow backend.
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2898, in run_code
self.showtraceback()

  File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1807, in showtraceback
self.showsyntaxerror(filename)

   File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1864, in showsyntaxerror
   stb = self.SyntaxTB.structured_traceback(etype, value, [])

   File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1441, in structured_traceback
   newtext = ulinecache.getline(value.filename, value.lineno)

   File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
   lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)

   File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
   return updatecache(filename, module_globals)

   File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
   lines = fp.readlines()

   File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 7588: invalid start byte
```

Comment: It's a file being decoded with the wrong codec. You need to find out (a) which file that is, (b) what its proper codec is, (c) where in the code it is opened, (d) change/add this codec as `encoding=` parameter in the `open()` call.

Comment: change open(filename) to open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')